# ASP.net Web API is it possible to use POST verb via Web Browser

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have tried researching about how to use POST verb all over the internet, some said that is it possible but not provided example. Is it really possible to use POST verb via Web Browser (Google Chrome) using URI? if so, then how?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you mean. Is it possible to send POST requests from a browser? Of course. Is it possible to have methods in WebAPI that respond to POST requests? Of course.

Comment: You normally use a tool for that like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen web browser using URI

Comment: What does that mean? Of course there is a URI and a browser. Specifics, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter of the controller action has a hint of [FromUri], one can try sending it sending the parameter values using query string. Otherwise, as mentioned above, you can use any of the three ways as below.
1. Use Fiddler to create the request.
2. From Chrome, you can send the request.
3. Write a simple http client application and pass the JSON object as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write any code then you can do so using something like https://www.getpostman.com/. It has a Google plugin so you can use it directly from your browser.